# Is the ObjectDataSource a good choice for professional (n-layer) applications?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, gridview, objectdatasource

I am asking this as there are many ways of populating a data control (like `GridView` and `FormsView`) and it can get overwhelming for a new developer.

What's the best approach?

Should data source controls (like `SqlDataSource` and `ObjectDataSource`) be avoided altogether?

Comment: `ObjectDataSource` - much better than the `SqlDataSource` for sure. Best bet in my opinion would be to use an enterprise-grade ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate - in conjunction with an `ObjectDataSource` or an `EntityDataSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `SqlDataSource` is not very appropiated for n-layered applications (except n = 1) since it talks directly to sql server.

On the other hand, `ObjectDataSource` is a perfectly acceptable option since allows you to call methods from classes on any of the layers the web layer has access to. It won't restrict your layers architecture at all.

Comment: And helps incoporate DRY principles into ur code